# How do you get the width of an element without a defined width?

Tags: html, css, width

How would you find out the width of a element that is wrapped by 20 odd other elements, but the only fixed width I know is the main wrapper's which is 800px. All child elements are generally blocks, floating or not, with different paddings and margins.
I don't really need the answer to a specific case, I'm just wondering if there are tools or tricks to quickly calculate such things.
Thanks

**EDIT:** Sorry to forget, this is on an external site where I can not install any scripts or edit the css.

Comment: Is this a programming question? How are you going to use the width value when you've obtained it?

Comment: It more sounds like that you're looking for a *tool*, not for *code*. You should have mentioned that a bit more explicitly or to ask at superuser.com.

Comment: I asked for *tools or tricks to quickly calculate such things* as I did not know the answer I did not know what to expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is your friend.

[How do you get the width of an element without a defined width? - Stack Overflow http://img.skitch.com/20100426-nequkipg8ex3khs1mux3tnctjb.preview.jpg](http://skitch.com/dorward/dyu52/how-do-you-get-the-width-of-an-element-without-a-defined-width-stack-overflow)

Comment: +1 because OP seems to be indeed looking for a tool. OP should please be more clear next time. All our discussion for naught!

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) that allows to find out the width of any DOM element reliably across browsers. Does that help?

Comment: Can you edit the html page itself?  If so, you can do this.  Refer to the hosted version of jquery.

Comment: It stands to reason, though, that using jQuery only for this is a bit overkill. I'd go with BalusC's answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`element.offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetWidth).

```
var width = element.offsetWidth;
```

Comment: It could be that I'm not really understanding the OP's question. If anybody can give some indication that this is the correct answer, I'll be happy to upvote :) (I didn't downvote either.) However, the OP can't use jQuery so you should get rid of the `$`.

Answer (score 2):

You can put **[JQuery](http://jquery.com)** to use and use its **[`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/)** method for that. The jQuery is smart enough to get the computed width of the element you specify.

Comment: @Moak: If you can not edit css or script and it is an external website you can not control, how can you be worried about getting elements' width, that's not possible :(

Comment: I can add a limited amount of html inside the element, my intention is to put in 3 even sized/spaced fonts, and for that i need the exact pixels.